# is it possible to install an Edge extension to a UWP app?

Tags: .net, uwp, microsoft-edge, hosted-app

I was wondering if we are able to load an Edge extension in an HTML-based UWP app.

Any info would be helpful, even installing during the building process or after that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions)  are small programs that can be used to add new features to Microsoft Edge. All the extensions are for Edge, they should not be installed directly on a UWP app.With the Windows 10 Creators Update, Microsoft Edge extensions are able to use [native messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging#demos) to communicate with a companion Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app. Tried to use UWP features to implement your requirements.